# Getting empty {} from mysql table, on React and node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs

For some reason am getting empty object back from mysql table, the table is filled in with some vacation detail. And i want to display them with map in my react app.

On the client side am doing the request with useEffect state and axios.

```
useEffect(() => {
        axios.get("http://localhost:3001/vacations")
            .then((response) => {
                let vacationsResponse = response.data;
                dispatch({ type: ActionType.GetAllVacations, payload: vacationsResponse })
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log("Failed to get data" + err)
            })
    }, [dispatch])
```

this is the server side:

```
const vacationsControllers = require("./Controllers/vacationsControllers");
const cors = require("cors");
server.use(cors({ origin: "http://localhost:3000" }));

server.use("/users", usersController);
server.use("/vacations", vacationsControllers);


server.listen(3001, () => console.log("Listening on http://localhost:3001"));
```

**this is the vacationsControllers folder:**

```
router.get("/", async (request, response) => {
  let vacationsData = request.body;

  try {
    await vacationsDao.getAllVacations(vacationsData);
    response.json();
    console.log(vacationsData)  *get this empty in the node terminal*
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    response.status(600).json();
  }
});


module.exports = router;
```

**The sql execute (the vacationDao folder):**

```
let connection = require("./connection-wrapper");

async function getAllVacations(vacationsData) {

  const sql = `SELECT * FROM current_deals`;

    await connection.executeWithParameters(sql);
      return vacationsData;
}


module.exports = {
  getAllVacations,
};
```

Comment: Looks like you aren't doing anything with the return value of `executeWithParameters`, you're just returning the same `vacationsData` that was passed into `getAllVacations`

Comment: It is unclear if you've made any modifications to the `mysql` module in your `executeWithParameters()` function. Please update your question to also show the contents of your `connection-wrapper` file. If everything in that file is working as intended you will still need to update your `getAllVacations()` function as @a544jh noted. Currently all you're doing is returning the same variable you took into the function to begin with. You'll want to assign the results of your awaited function to a new variable, then return that.

Comment: Thank you very much your answer helped me a lot!  I gave the `vacationData` parameter to await connection.